# First value in subsequents rows that match a condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gaps-and-islands

| order_at | delivery_at |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 |
| 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-05 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-05 |

I want a new field, `next_delivery_at`, which is the first `delivery_at` in subsequents rows for each `delivery_at`, that is not the same value as `delivery_at` so the final table would be:

| order_at | delivery_at | next_delivery_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-05 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-05 |
| 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-05 | null |
| 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-05 | null |

For this specific case, I could do something like:

```
CASE
      WHEN (LEAD(delivery_at) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY delivery_at DESC) = delivery_at)
      THEN (LEAD(delivery_at, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY delivery_at DESC))
      ELSE LEAD(delivery_at) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY delivery_at DESC)
  END AS next_delivery_at
```

But if there are more than two rows in a row with the same `delivery_at`, the output will be wrong, so I am looking for a generic way of getting the first value in subsequents rows for `delivery_at` that is distinct for each delivery_at value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join to match successive deliveries, then get the minimum next delivery.

```
SELECT t1.order_at, t1.delivery_at, MIN(t2.delivery_at) AS next_delivery_at
FROM      tab t1
LEFT JOIN tab t2
       ON t1.delivery_at < t2.delivery_at
GROUP BY t1.order_at, t1.delivery_at
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below using a logical window frame **[RANGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#def_window_frame)**

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '2023-01-01' order_at, '2023-01-03' delivery_at UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-01-02' order_at, '2023-01-03' delivery_at UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-01-03' order_at, '2023-01-05' delivery_at UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-01-04' order_at, '2023-01-05' delivery_at
)
SELECT *,
       FIRST_VALUE(delivery_at) OVER (
         ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(DATE(delivery_at))
         RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
       ) AS next_delivery_at
  FROM sample_table;
```

**Query results**

[image]